# TypeError: len() of unsized object como resolver

Tags: python-3.x

```
def invert_map(x):
    y = _np.empty_like(x)
    y[x] = _np.arange(len(x))
    return y
```

Resultado dá isto nesta função :

> File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\arlpy\comms.py", line 74, in invert_map
>      y[x] = _np.arange(len(x))
>
> TypeError: len() of unsized object

Qual a sua causa? Como resolvê-lo?

Comment: Qual o `x` sendo passado para ele disparar esse erro?

Comment: A função `len` faz uso do método `__len__` do objeto, portanto `x` precisa ser do tipo que possui a implementação deste método, caso contrário este erro será lançado.

Answer (score -1):

Provavelmente "x" não é uma string.

Tente convertê-la, assim:

```
len(str(TestV))
```

Comment: E deveria ser uma *string*?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Bem pensado, fui direto no uso mais comum haha! Mas a "len" serve para listas também.